# Rails + jquery: how can I pass json from jquery into my rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Saw many similar requests but nothing made sense:
I'm using the Google API geocoder to get detailed info on an address and what I get in return from the API is data in json format. I'm trying to pass this json data to my rails controller for further processing. So in my view, I have the following jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#address").blur(function(){
        var address = $("#address").val();
        if(address != ""){
          processAddress(address, function(data, s){        
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: "pages/process",
                data: data,
                success: function(msg) {
                  $(".processed-info").html(msg);
                }
              });        
          });
        }
      });
```

processAddress returns a json object which i read in as "data" and I want to pass this data to my rails controller where I want to receive it as:

```
def process
  @address_json = ...
end
```

I've tried many combinations of things and no point in cluttering the question. Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the json object as a query paramater in the URL.
Instead of passing the straight JSON back to rails, you should set a query param = to your json data.  You want your URL to end up as `pages/process?api_json=data`.
With the way you currently have it you would be passing in each attribute of the json into a sperate query param.

Try somethign like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#address").blur(function(){
    var address = $("#address").val();
    if(address != ""){
      processAddress(address, function(data, s){        
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "pages/process",
            data: { google_json: data },
            success: function(msg) {
              $(".processed-info").html(msg);
            }
          });        
      });
    }
  });
```

From there in your controller you would have:

```
def process
  @address_json = params[:google_json]
end
```